# How to add user permisson to directory?

Tags: command-line, server, permissions

How can I give user or group write permissons to a folder? in terminal session.
I allready know how to change folder permission/owner.
I want to give user or group write permission to a folder without affecting the previous owner or permissions to the folder.

I guess the question is can you give multible users acces to a folder like you do in windows?
or maybe just add the user to a group that allready has access?

:)

Answer (score 1):

you can use ACLs for that.

```
setfacl -m u:username:rwx /path/to/folder
```

- u: for username
- g: for group
- replace username with groupname for groups
- for folder use -R for recursive permissions.

If more information needed, just google for Linux ACLs, you will get tons of information.